# Persistent Background Service

Tags: android

I have an assignment of moving the png file of a signature to one of our servers. The solution I implemented is to have a background service that monitors the folder it is saved in then move it. This works well  but the service shuts down after a certain period of time, might be an hour or something, but I'd like it to be persistent. Doing some research resulted in either using a alarm manager or a handler to keep the activity alive.

I decided to use the handler. However whenever the activity is called the device hangs and it takes more memory every time I refresh it. The culprit may be due to not calling 'stopWatching()' though it is possible I handled the problem incorrectly.

**SendToPHP.java**

```
public class SendToPHP extends Activity {
final int FIFTEEN_MINUTES_IN_MILLISECONDS = 900000;

//The handler will run the function restart at a later time
//This should prevent the intent service timeout.
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(SendToPHP.this,
                BackgroundService.class);
        // Starts the IntentService
        SendToPHP.this.startService(mServiceIntent);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, FIFTEEN_MINUTES_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    }

}
```

**BackgroundService.java**

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "*redacted*";

    //FileObserver monitors files/directories, in this case we want any file that is
    //created in SignItPictures
    FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(android.os.Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/SignItPictures", FileObserver.CREATE ) { 
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
            uploadFileName = file;
            uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "/" + uploadFileName);
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching(); // start the observer
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing that? Can't you just upload it once saved?

Comment: "This works well but the service shuts down after a certain period of time, might be an hour or something, but I'd like it to be persistent" -- your users may well disagree. Do not keep a service in memory solely twiddling its fingers. Only have a service in memory when it is actively delivering value to the user. The problem is not that your service is shutting down, but that Android is terminating your process, to free up memory for other apps. Users will terminate your process as well, using task managers and the like, and you do not want to tempt them into doing this.

Comment: @rciovati its for my Internship, the android device simply sits at a desk and receives signatures for IT devices that and borrowed.
at commonsware Hmm, I guess I could have an app that process the whole folder since this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding START_STICKY in the onStartCommand method of your Service class